# Ream swift migration crash only on device

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-migration

I have to update my realm schema by adding a field on one of the objects.

Here is the migration code:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 4,

        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 4) {
                print("Updating Realm schema...")
                // Nothing to do!
            }
    })
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    let realm = try! Realm()

    // ... rest of code
}
```

- It's OK when running on the simulator
- It's OK when running on a device from xCode

But If I install the app from TestFairy or TestFlight, the app crashes right at launch. When I remove migration everything is fine, so the migration causes the problem.

Symbolicating the crash report do not help, the crash is at start of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Tried various export option changes (bitcode, ...) but same result.

Do you see any reason why a migration could fail when the updated app is not installed from xCode ?

Comment: try to add 1 to the schemaVersion  (5)

Comment: When you run on a device try to increase version. Maybe on a device already more than 4.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the reason. The app is already on the device with schema version 0. Updating it through xCode is OK ; updating it from TestFlight crashes. The version sent to TestFlight or TestFairy is the same as the one who works from xCode. The only difference is that I archived it and uploaded it.

Comment: archive new one with higher scheme number and try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you distribute the application to **Test Flight** or to the **AppStore**,

You should add one to the scheme, for instance if your application recent build
 has schema number of `4` on the **test flight** the new build should be `5` if you have any changes to the realm classes however if you are locally trying to test things out you can just delete the application and reinstall it via `Xcode`.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#local-migrations).

Comment: My previous schema number was 0, I can see it because I printed it on the logs. Anyway I changed new scheme number from 4 to 5 as you suggested, and there is no crash anymore. That's weird imho, but the problem is solved and I thank you very much to have insisted on this idea :)

Comment: No problem I’ve been there with realm that’s why